# When I select some text, I want it to be copied to clipboard automatically

Tags: linux, clipboard

Let's say you have firefox open on centos linux desktop. Or simply some basic text editor.

You select a text. Soon as the mouse button is up. In other words selecting is done.

I want it to copy it to clipboard. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I have to admit I'm a little puzzled at the downvotes to this question. This isn't a great question, but it isn't terrible either. There's a clear goal stated, and it specifies the environment pretty well. Recognizing select-then-middleclick to copy text doesn't necessarily come easy to someone coming e.g. from Windows, because Windows has nothing like that.

Comment: Maybe because what is asked already exists natively and is well explaned all over the internet ?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Newbie questions are annoying to seasoned users because the new user is refusing to solve a problem by research before asking. I have read instructions on how to copy and paste in "Linux" with a mouse involuntarily on at least 3 occasions after learning about the concept. I find it strange that someone would need to ask about this. At best, they are lazy - which is seldom appreciated. Another reason, is I don't want this site to be a solution center for children because I want to learn from these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try selecting some text and then middle-click a text area of some kind. That should work in common graphical Linux environments.

It uses a buffer that is usually called "primary selection", which exists along side the "clipboard selection"; in practice they can be used to the same effect. Some cross-platform applications act a bit strangely with regards to these dual concepts, but mostly it interacts well.

Comment: I do not want to middle-click, i want to simply select the text and let go, on that letting go, i want to execute a command such as `xdotool key ctrl+c`

Comment: If you select text, you will automatically copy it to the "primary selection" buffer, which is separate from the "clipboard selection". I repeat: the text is automatically copied to this buffer when you select text. You _paste_ it by middle-clicking somewhere. If this is not sufficient for your use case, edit your question to say why.